# type error in using typescript and mongodb findOneAndUpdate method

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb

This is my mongodb collection model

```
export class User {
    constructor(
        public _id: ObjectId,
        public username: string,
        public phone: string,
        public password: string,
        public pages: Array<ObjectId>
    ) { }
}
```

I want to add new ObjectId into pages:

```
const pageID = new ObjectId()
const result1 = await userCollection.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: new ObjectId(userID)
    }, {
        $push: {
            pages: pageID
        }
    })
```

And there is an error near $push

```
Type '{ pages: ObjectId; }' is not assignable to type 'PushOperator<Document>'.
  Type '{ pages: ObjectId; }' is not assignable to type 'NotAcceptedFields<Document, readonly any[]>'.
    Property 'pages' is incompatible with index signature.
      Type 'ObjectId' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
```

I found lots of examples in js and shell, but none in ts. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem after updating to MongoDB driver v4.9.0. The solution is to cast your update object to `Record<string, any>`:

```
const pageID = new ObjectId();
const updateObj: Record<string, any> = {
    pages: pageID
};
const result1 = await userCollection.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: new ObjectId(userID) }, 
    { $push: updateObj }
);
```

The reason is the following PR: [3349](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/pull/3349), which changed the definition of `MatchKeysAndValues`, and affected the `update` argument of the following functions: `updateOne`, `updateMany`, `findOneAndUpdate`, `update`.